# Process appear by "netstat" but doesn't appear by "ps -a"

Tags: process, ps, netstat

I have a machine in my organization that I sshed and received a terminal.

When I run `netstat -ntlp` I received:

```
[root@webtl1 ~]# netstat -ntlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5355            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      527/systemd-resolve
tcp6       0      0 :::5355                 :::*                    LISTEN      527/systemd-resolve
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1/systemd
```

When I run `ps -a` I received:

```
[root@webtl1 ~]# ps -a
  PID  TTY          TIME CMD
  1165 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
```

I don't see the process `systemd-resolve`. 
But if I run `ps -p 527` I do see it:

```
[root@webtl1 ~]# ps -p 527
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
  527 ?        00:00:00 systemd-resolve
```

Why I don't see it with `ps -a` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple `ps` shows only your own processes, not system processes or other users' processes. `ps` allows options to show more processes, e.g. `ps ax` or `ps -e` or `ps -A`.

`ps -a` doesn't show the process `systemd-resolve` because it's not associated with a terminal. See [`man ps`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html) for details.

Comment: Why not mentioning ps -ax?

Comment: @Rui `ps -ax` is `ps ax` (`-x` doesn’t exist so it’s interpreted as a BSD option), which is mentioned.